# A word that encompasses both creating and editing something

Tags: verbs

I am combining two website-based editors (one for create, one for edit) into one, and am trying to think of a word that encompasses both creating and editing in one.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @ermanen The answers there aren't really applicable, since that question is about creating/updating elements in programming, not documents. Words like _assign_ don't fit here.

Comment: Next you'll be asking why we have "New" and "Open" as separate words and how to combine them in one.